# $display every time $monitor works in Verilog

Tags: verilog

In a Verilog testbench I have a `$monitor` statement that looks something like this:

```
initial begin  
$monitor("a=%h, b=%h",a,b)  
end
```

This means that both `a` and `b` are in the monitor's sensitivity list. What I actually want to do is just monitor changes to `a`, and when `a` changes display `b`'s value. I can't figure out how to do this. Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 10):

I do not think that behaviour is possible with monitor, but you could always just display when `a` changes:

```
always @(a) begin  
  $display("a=%h, b=%h",a,b);
end
```